# Laravel 8 Many to Many relationship not working (no errors being thrown)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel but am having a very odd issue.

I successfully created models and migrations for 6 tables to work with many-to-many relationships. One of the relationships works fine and I can retrieve data through a route. The other, however, only returns a white screen (no error, no nothing). The networking tab response says: "This request has no response data available" - but I've triple checked the database and search for different records and it never returns any results.

I've kept the information as simple as possible and followed all naming conventions.

Any idea what is going on here? Is something configured wrong? Please help me from going crazy - I've tried a ton of code iterations and nothing seems to work to establish the many to many client/network relationship.

**Not Working Relationship**

Client table:

```
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_name    | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| client_type_id | bigint unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address        | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address_2      | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city           | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state          | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip_code       | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country        | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Network table:

```
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| network_name | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

client_network table:

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id  | bigint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| network_id | bigint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Client model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function networks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Network::class);
    }
}
```

Network model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Network extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
    }
}
```

Route:

```php
Route::get('/testclient', function() {
    $network = Client::find(1)->network_name;
    return $network;
});
```

Comment: Hi there! Just to make sure, one post belong to many comments? I would do as the wiki says, a One To Many (& Inverse) Relationship so that one post has many comments and many comments can belong to one post! https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: If you try like: $network = Client::find(1);
    return $network->client();

Comment: @Prospero that throws a 'bad method' error. Plus the other Models/methods for the Posts/Comments relationship are working fine as is.

Comment: @GreenPepper ya, it’s a bit confusing but this is just some test data so I’ve got many comments relating to many posts. That data is working perfectly, it’s the client/network relationship that is having issues even those the code is almost identical.

Comment: Can you share the Client or Network migration file code?

Comment: One personal recommendation, **do not name singular, what is a many resource**. If your `clients` can have multiple `networks` and vice-versa, do not name the relations as `client()` and `network()` because those will return a `collection`, but if you read those as singular you expect to get a model instead... You can also do `dd(Client::find(1)->network);` and share the results.

Comment: Your intermediate table is `client_network` and not `Client_network` right? Maybe add the extra arguments as in `return $this->belongsToMany(Network::class, 'client_network', 'network_id', 'client_id');` and the same for `return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'client_network, 'client_id, 'network_id');`. Indeed use plural is in `clients()` etc. As they are collections you will iterate through in blade. If that doesn't work, You will have to share more Model code of these classes.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey correct, my intermediate table is client_network (I've changed it above for accuracy). I've tried the extra arguments in all iterations:
- adding the intermediate table to both methods with no ids
- adding the intermediate table and both ids
- adding the intermediate table and both ids but flipped (just to try)

All attempts still returned nothing..

Comment: @Prospero I'm curious what the migration file would show that wouldn't be reflected in the table structures above?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you! Your comment lead me down the path to getting the answer. The relationship was correct, the issue was with the route. The dd() returned the data and  all I had to do was loop through the clients to pull out the information.

I'm new to SO, how do I give you credit for an answer?

Comment: @shaiden, because the most of conventions even for Laravel use plural names for tables and in this case relationships statements in model classes is in plural too for elocuent collection data retrieves

Comment: @shaiden Don't worry, just vote up my comment and done ! If you want, you can add an answer to your own post with the correct solution so everyone can see the actual solution ! Glad I was able to help you !

Comment: @matiaslauriti Shoot... I'm 2 reputation points shy of being able to upvote your comment. Once I get there, I will.

In the meantime, Ill add the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone dealing with a similar issue, the problem in this situation was not the relationship, it was the route extracting the data from the relationship.

**Not Working Route**

```
Route::get('/testclient', function() {
    $network = Client::find(1)->network_name;
    return $network;
});
```

**Working Route**

```
Route::get('/testing', function(){

    $networks = Client::find(1)->networks;

    foreach($networks as $network){

        $network_arr[] = $network->network_name;

    }

    return $network_arr;
```

To solve the issue, the suggested code in the comments helped to show that data was indeed being extracted from the relationship but not displaying properly.

**Helper Code:**

```
dd(Network::find(1)->clients);
```

Comment: You can have a more "laravel way" code if you change the `foreach` to [map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map), you should end with a function doing this: `return $network->network_name;` and it will automatically end up with another collection. If you need to have an array you then do `->toArray()` but if you are going to iterate that collection, there is no need to cast it to array.

Answer (score 0):

You make a typo, change

```
Route::get('/testclient', function() {
    $network = Client::find(1)->network;
    return $network;
});
```

To

```
Route::get('/testclient', function() {
    $network = Client::find(1)->networks; //Add s
    return $network;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that is still not returning any data. I've changed the Route above to reflect the current iteration.